# PayPal Authentication API Using Google Apps Script. Why does my authentication keep failing?

Tags: rest, google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to make the authentication API call to get the access token for my PayPal account, but I keep running into an error: `{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client Authentication failed"}`

I've double and triple checked my client_id and client_secret to make sure I've copied them to the Script Properties section of my project correctly. The API call works in Postman just fine, but I can't seem to get it in Google Apps script. Here's my code:

```
function retrieveInfo() {
  try {
    const scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
    const clientId = scriptProperties.getProperty('CLIENT_ID');
    const secret = scriptProperties.getProperty('SECRET');
    const final = `<${clientId}>:<${secret}>`;
    return Utilities.base64Encode(final, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Failed with error %s', err.message);
  }
}

function bearerTolken() {
  const clientInfo = retrieveInfo();

  var requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Authorization': `Basic ${clientInfo}`,
    },
    body: {
      grant_type: 'client_credentials',
      ignoreCache: 'true',
      return_authn_schemes: 'true',
      return_client_metadata: 'true',
      return_unconsented_scopes: 'true'
    },
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  };

  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token", requestOptions);
  console.log(response.toString());
  console.log(response.getResponseCode());

}
```

I've tried formatting the body of the call multiple different ways, I believe the issue is has to do with the grant_type or my translation of the URLSearchParams class, but I can't seem to find anyone else with a similar issue. When I tested the call in Postman, I copied the Javascript - Fetch code and translated it to Apps script.Here's the copied code from Postman:

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Basic {{CREDENTIALS HERE}}");

var urlencoded = new URLSearchParams();
urlencoded.append("grant_type", "client_credentials");
urlencoded.append("ignoreCache", "true");
urlencoded.append("return_authn_schemes", "true");
urlencoded.append("return_client_metadata", "true");
urlencoded.append("return_unconsented_scopes", "true");

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: urlencoded,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

There is no "Header" class nor is there a "URLSearchParams" class so I included those key/value pairs in the requestOptions variable instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [basic HTTP authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) there are no less than nor greater than signs in the string to then encode and send in the Authorization header...

```
 const final = `${clientId}:${secret}`;
```

The only non-header data in the request should be `grant_type=client_credentials`, exactly; omit other parameters as they are not needed or relevant.

---

If you continue to have issues, test with command line curl and log the full request and response, including the sandbox client_id and secret being tested with. That is if you want anyone to be of additional help.

Comment: Thank you! I removed the body out of the request, removed the `<>` signs in the final variable, and added `grant_type=client_credentials` to the URL params. That seemed to do the trick!

Comment: It might work either way but `grant_type=client_credentials` should be in the POST data, not a GET/URL string